# Sitecore xm personalization rules - graphql, jss v18.1

Tags: personalization, graphql

Is it possible to create `personalization rules` for `conditional rendering` in `Sitecore XM` with `JSS` version 18.1? We currently use `GraphQL` to get the content. I want to personalize this content using data that I have in my front-end session. But there is the problem, it is in the front-end session/state and not in the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

No, conditional rendering rules are not surfaced through the GraphQL Edge endpoint. If you want to personalize in Headless JSS with Next.js, you need to be using a dedicated personalization service like Sitecore Personalize.

Comment: It this possible in xm cloud without the personalization module when you just use url parameters or session variables?

Answer (score 0):

No, Conditional rendering is often used as a synonym for personalized content. It is not, however, a synonym for personalization. Personalization refers to the broad process of delivering targeted, relevant content to visitors.

In a Sitecore XM installation, the functionality that you can use is different depending on how you installed Sitecore XM, for example:

- If you used the Sitecore XP topology packages (XP Scaled or XP Single) to install Sitecore XP and then configured it to run in CMS-only mode, some of the personalization conditions are available and you can implement in-session personalization.
- If you used the Sitecore XM Scaled topology packages to install Sitecore XM, a smaller set of personalization conditions are available and you can implement in-session personalization with the available conditions.

**Personalization** – You can implement some in-session personalization rules, such as ones based on IP Geolocation, to provide personalized content to your contacts. You cannot, however, implement any personalization rules that are based on historical data, such as outcomes or past goals triggered.

As you are using XM with Headless JSS and GraphQL, It would be great to use Sitecore Personalize to meet your requirements and make it future-proof.

References:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/experience-manager.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/conditional-renderings.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/the-personalization-conditions.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/personalize/en/developers/api/index-en.html

Hope it helps!